# counter characters from a text file in python

Tags: python

I have a text file in python. This text file is like this:

```
Aragon is an autonomous community in northeastern Spain. The capital of Aragon is Zaragoza, which is also the most populous city in the autonomous community. Covering an area of ​​47720 km2, the region's terrain ranges from permanent glaciers through verdant valleys, rich pastures and orchards to the arid steppe plains of the central lowlands. Aragon is home to many rivers, most notably the Ebro, Spain's largest river, which flows west to east throughout the region through the province of Zaragoza. It is also home to the highest mountains in the Pyrenees.
```

Now I would like to create a dict from collections to count how many times each character occur.

I gave the following  code for read the text file

```
with open("data/aragon.txt",'r') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        data = line.lower().strip().split()
        print(data)
```

Now I would like to now if there is an easier way to count the occurence of each character or is this the only method

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(['A','r','a','g','o','n','i','s','a','n','a','u','t','o','n','o','m','o','u','s','c','o','m','m','u','n','i','t','y','i','n','n','o','r','t','h','e','a','s','t','e','r','n','S','p','a','i','n','.'])
```

I did that just for the first phrase. But I would like to know if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are nearly there, the counter object has a dictionary-like interface, so, you can call `update` on it with the string to update its internal contents.

```py
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
with open("data/aragon.txt",'r') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        data = line.lower().strip()  # no split is needed
        counter.update(data)
        print(data)
print(counter)
```

Comment: But this code doesn't count for example every a in the whole text?

Comment: @Jaime every time you call `update` it counts the repeat number of each letter in the new text and add it to the old counters, what do you mean by `doesn't count every a`, do you mean like it outputs both `A` and `a` in the same counter (because you used `lower`) or do you mean that it doesn't count every `a` in text, as in it misses some `a` in the text ?